# PHP upload image to a specified folder

Tags: php

I got this code from: https://github.com/hemantrai88/html5-php_multi-file-upload

I want to make it upload to a folder specified from an input.

Can someone help me?

```
   $input = $_POST["input"];

mkdir('/uploads/'. $input, 0777, true);

if(isset($_REQUEST['AddFiles'])){
$targetFolder = 'uploads/' . $input; //Path to the Uploads Folder 
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['upload_file']['name']);$i++){
            $tempFile = $_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $targetFile = rtrim($targetFolder,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['upload_file']['name'][$i];
            $fileTypes = array('jpeg','jpg','png','gif'); // Allowed File extensions
            $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['upload_file']['name'][$i]);
            if(isset($fileParts['extension'])){
                if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
                    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
                    echo '<div class="success">'.$_FILES['upload_file']['name'][$i].' was saved successfully inside '.$targetFolder.' Directory</div>';
                }else{
                    echo '<div class="fail">'.$_FILES['upload_file']['name'][$i].' couldn\'t be saved because of invalid file type.</div>';
                }
            }else{
                echo '<div class="fail">'.$_FILES['upload_file']['name'][$i].' couldn\'t be saved because of invalid file type.</div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions asking for code should **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) .

Comment: I've added my code above, @JohnConde

Comment: So what is not working? I see you already added the folder as `$input`.

Comment: the folder isn't getting created, @putvande

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkdir('/uploads/'. $input, 0777, true);
```

should be:

```
mkdir('uploads/'. $input, 0777, true);
```

that should work